# Redirecting on cancel in Rails 'confirm' button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-dialog, confirm

I'm using Rails 4.0.3 and trying to create a customized Confirm dialog box.
This is not a site-wide change, but I would like it to be an optional parameter for a link/button akin to confirm:"Are you sure?"

The goal is to replicate the syntax of saying: <% button_to [...] , confirm: "are you sure?" %>

In one instance, clicking 'cancel' should redirect the user to another page.

Ideally, I would like to say something along the lines of <% button_to [...] , confirm-with-redirect: "are you sure?" %>

While it is possible to write custom javascript, I would like to be able to use a uniform syntax across all pages, and I am not sure to integrate this properly. Googling generally just turns up people discussing inserting modals into confirm dialogs.

Any answers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  When posting questions, we prefer that you show that you've attempted to answer the question already. What did Google tell you?

Comment: Use javascript confirm() method. The answer is a little less generic than the question...

Comment: edited to clarify the goal